# List only the column names of a dataset

Tags: sas

I am working on SAS in UNIX env and I want to view only the column name of a dataset. I have tried proc contents and proc print but both of them list a lot of other irrevelant information that I do not want as it fills up my putty screen and the information ultimately is lost.

I also tried to get this thing frm the sas metadata but that is not working either.
I tried :

```
  2? proc sql;
  select *
 from dictionary.tables
 where libname='test' and memname='sweden_elig_file_jul';
quit;
  5?
NOTE: No rows were selected.

  6?
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           0.27 seconds
      cpu time            0.11 seconds
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're using the wrong dictionary table to get column names...

```
proc sql ;
  select name 
  from dictionary.columns
  where memname = 'MYDATA'
  ;
quit ;
```

Or using PROC CONTENTS

```
proc contents data=mydata out=meta (keep=NAME) ; 
run ; 
proc print data=meta ; run ;
```

Comment: I second Chris J's answer. But, would not recommend the `dictionary.columns` way - it can be many times slower than the `proc contents` way especially if you have a large number of tables in your SAS environment.

Comment: The sql query approach didn't output the variable names for me, but the proc contents code worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one I've used before to get a list of columns with a little bit more information, you can add the keep option as in the previous answer. This just demonstrates how to create a connection to the metadata server, in case that is useful to anyone viewing this post.

```
libname fetchlib meta 
    library="libraryName" metaserver="metaDataServerAddress"
    password="yourPassword" port=1234
    repname="yourRepositoryName" user="yourUserName";

proc contents data=fetchlib.YouDataSetName
    memtype=DATA 
    out=outputDataSet 
    nodetails 
    noprint; 
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

For a pure macro approach, try the following:

```
%macro mf_getvarlist(libds
      ,dlm=%str( )
)/*/STORE SOURCE*/;
  /* declare local vars */
  %local outvar dsid nvars x rc dlm;
  /* open dataset in macro */
  %let dsid=%sysfunc(open(&libds));

  %if &dsid %then %do;
    %let nvars=%sysfunc(attrn(&dsid,NVARS));
    %if &nvars>0 %then %do;
      /* add first dataset variable to global macro variable */
      %let outvar=%sysfunc(varname(&dsid,1));
      /* add remaining variables with supplied delimeter */
      %do x=2 %to &nvars;
        %let outvar=&outvar.&dlm%sysfunc(varname(&dsid,&x));
      %end;
    %End;
    %let rc=%sysfunc(close(&dsid));
  %end;
  %else %do;
    %put unable to open &libds (rc=&dsid);
    %let rc=%sysfunc(close(&dsid));
  %end;
  &outvar
%mend;
```

Usage:

```
%put List of Variables=%mf_getvarlist(sashelp.class);
```

Returns:

> List of Variables=Name Sex Age Height Weight

source:  https://github.com/sasjs/core/blob/main/base/mf_getvarlist.sas

Answer (score -1):

```
proc sql;
    select *
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname="TEST" and memname="SWEDEN_ELIG_FILE_JUL";
quit;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can make this answer better by [edit]ing it to explain how it works.